# how to get and split word when get it form the Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to get a `String` from the `ListView` that I have but when I use `getItemPostion` the result isn't right.

My list of items are

```
4WIFI
5WIFI
6WIFI
```

and when i use

```
 ListView lv;
String network = lv.getItemAtPosition(0).toString;
```

the result is

```
"{key=4WIFI}"
```

the result that i want is

```
4WIFI
```

and this is code of my list

```
ITEM_KEY = "key"

this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);
```

and this is code for add item to my array

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public void onClick(View view)
{
    arraylist.clear();
    wifi.startScan();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try
    {
        size = size - 1;
        while (size >= 0)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID);
            arraylist.add(item);
            size--;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }
}
```

please guide me on what should I do

Comment: Post how you get `"{key=4WIFI}"` and your `arraylist` initialization.

Comment: `getItemPosition` probably returns `Object` an you just want a `String` Probably typecast can fix this. Also you can use `arraylist.get(position)` to achieve the same.

Comment: Please paste your full code. so that we can see how your {key=4WIFI} is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where or how you are getting those `String` as you do, but one solution might be this:

```
String YourString; // Already containing "{key=4WIFI}" etc
String OmitFirstPart;
if(YourString.startsWith("{key=")){
for (OmitFirstPart: YourString.split("=", 6)){
     OmitFirstPart=YourString;
  }
String OmitLastPart=OmitFirstPart.split("}", -5);
```

that is all.

Comment: if i don't know text length but i know a text form what should i do for solve it?

Comment: @KanokKonglar in that case make 6 in the loop as much as the longest string yours

Comment: @KanokKonglar and just omit the -5, just pass "}"